# Generate a list from columns that do not contain a zero for each row

Tags: oracle, select

I have a table `TAB1` in an Oracle database:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  0 |  3 |  0 |  5 |
|  2 | 11 | 22 |  0 | 44 |  0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I need a select statement that gives me the following output:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id |          descr          |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | column1,column3,column5 |
|  2 | column1,column2,column4 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

...meaning I need in to concatenate names for every column (not exactly the name of the column but a different text for every column) that is not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
select
  id,
  rtrim(
    case when c1 != 0 then 'column1,' end
 || case when c2 != 0 then 'column2,' end
 || case when c3 != 0 then 'column3,' end
 || case when c4 != 0 then 'column4,' end
 || case when c5 != 0 then 'column5' end, ',') as descr
from tab1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

1. Unpivot the columns.
2. Filter out the 0's.
3. Group by ID and concatenate the column names.

Something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a6f6/3) (assuming you are using Oracle 11g):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  LISTAGG(Col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col) AS descr
FROM
  atable
UNPIVOT
  (
    Val FOR Col IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)
  ) u
WHERE
  Val <> 0
GROUP BY
  ID
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a concatenation of every field in the form of:

```
CASE WHEN columnX!=0 THEN 'textX,' ELSE '' END
```

This would make:

```
select id, trim(CASE WHEN column1!=0 THEN 'text1,' ELSE '' END||
                CASE WHEN column2!=0 THEN 'text2,' ELSE '' END||
                CASE WHEN column3!=0 THEN 'text3,' ELSE '' END||
                CASE WHEN column4!=0 THEN 'text4,' ELSE '' END||
                CASE WHEN column5!=0 THEN 'text5' ELSE '' END, ',') as descr
from   tab1;
```